# How do I retrieve an access token returned in Program.cs to be available in Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm using a third party API that requires me to get an access token to send with the Authorization header in each request. Since sending calls to this API is an integral part of the app, I want to grab the access token as soon as the app is started. I have code in my `Program.cs` file with a `GetToken` async method that runs in `Main()`, which makes the call to the authorization endpoint and returns the access token.

My trouble is that in `Startup.cs`, I have an `AddHttpClient()` method chained to my `services` in my `ConfigureServices()` method, which sets up the HTTP Client, and I need to add the access token to the authentication header. Is my approach completely off? I'm not entirely sure where to go from here.

Comment: How long does this access token last for? i.e. Does it expire? If it does, requesting it just once at Startup is going to cause problems for you.

Comment: Hi @KirkLarkin! You're right, it does. Thanks for pointing that out. I guess one other way l can think of is to call `GetToken()` from an auth controller which will fire at the root page and have the service class create the HttpClient? Is that a better approach?

Comment: I would recommend reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#outgoing-request-middleware).

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thank you, will try creating a handler!

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the Auth call inside your `StartUp` class and pass it to your `AddHttpClient()` method. You can await `GetToken()` there, as the returned token is integral for all HttpClients to use it as a header. Theoretically, it should take exactly the same amount of time whether you put it inside `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs`

Comment: Hey @Eyassu! Thanks for your suggestion. I am adding the HttpClients in the `ConfigureServices` method, which is currently not async. Do you suggest that I make the `ConfigureServices` method async, and then call the `GetToken()` in the beginning of this method?

Comment: An `async` version of `ConfigureServices` isn't supported. For this approach, you'd have to consider using `.Result` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but that's considered to be a bad idea in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @dbgywjd It's okay to do a .Result, if it doesn't make sense to proceed without the necessary token.